# Find by class name can not found elements

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, yandex-maps

https://parselsorgu.tkgm.gov.tr/

in this webpage, i am trying to find elements in satelite yandex view, but selenium cannot find anything in this section. how can i find elements in this satelite yandex view.
if i press inspect, i can see the codes, but can not reach them..

```
sinir=sinir.find_elements_by_class_name('leaflet-zoom-animated')
```

gets, error.
it can get from drop box menus, but cannot get satelite yandex view part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it as;

```
//*[@id="map-canvas"]/div[@class='leaflet-pane leaflet-map-pane']/div[@class='leaflet-pane leaflet-overlay-pane']//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g']
```

All you need to use is the name() tag.

I found this element by selecting random area from the left bar.

element is not visible by class name, you can use name() = 'svg'

I think this will help you to understand..